# Protractor loop: while until some text in text field is appeared

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to realize a loop with "while' construction for scrolling down a table with loading dynamic data until some text like "n of N items displayed
 (scroll for more)"  changes to text like "N of N items displayed" in label element. New data are loaded by blocks in 30 rows scrolling to the bottom of table. I'm trying to realize a loop:

```
var Needed_text = 'needed_text';
var rows = element.all(by.xpath('table'));
var text = element(by.xpath('element').getText();
while(expect((text).not.toEqual(Needed_text)){
        last_row = rows.last();
        row_count_number = rows.count(rows);
        browser.actions().mouseMove(last_row).perform();
        browser.sleep(3000);
        text = element(by.xpath('element').getText();
});
```

All a time when I'm trying to realize something like that I face error :

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory

Trying to fix this bug with changing parameters *max_old_space* and etc. didn't help me. How can i rebuild this loop for scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to declare a boolean variable that will change once you get the desired label. And then, you look for that element inside the while loop, but in order to check the desired text you will have to resolve the promise. Something like this:

```
var bool = true;
while (bool) {
    element(by.xpath('element').getText().then(function(resolvedText){
    if (resolvedText == NeededText){
        do all you need here;
        bool = false;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks,@zuraik but it would work in java, c++ or something like that. In Protractor your code leads to the same error:
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Loops work if we clearly define borders (like while(i<100) for example).

Answer (score 0):

if your logic is correct below code should work. 
getText() method returns a promise and it needs to be resolved .

```
element(by.xpath('element').getText().then(function(text){
while(expect((text).not.toEqual(Needed_text)){
        last_row = rows.last();
        row_count_number = rows.count(rows);
        browser.actions().mouseMove(last_row).perform();
        browser.sleep(3000);
        text = element(by.xpath('element').getText();
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks.The error:"'JavaScript heap out of memory " is disappeared but test fail without any error. Loop "while" doesn't work with any undefined parameters.